# App lags on huge Core Data mappings via RestKit & Magical Record

Tags: ios, multithreading, core-data, restkit

Im [still trying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29481867/restkit-core-data-magical-record-lots-of-data-and-lagging-ui) to figure out what loads the UI thread. In a class(a child of UITableView) there's a FRC:

```
 NSFetchRequest *request = [DEPlace MR_requestAllWithPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"isWorking == YES"]];

 request.sortDescriptors = @[ [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES] ];
 self.placesController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:request
                                                                managedObjectContext:[NSManagedObjectContext MR_rootSavingContext]
                                                                  sectionNameKeyPath:nil
                                                                           cacheName:nil];
 self.placesController.delegate = self;
```

It used to be attached to a MR_contextForCurrentThread. Changing it to rootSavingContext slightly affected the performance. Then i set both root and default contexts to the same one:

```
[NSManagedObjectContext MR_setRootSavingContext:managedObjectStore.persistentStoreManagedObjectContext];
[NSManagedObjectContext MR_setDefaultContext:managedObjectStore.persistentStoreManagedObjectContext];
```

Default context used to be set to mainQueueManagedObjectContext. I want to move literally everything core data related to background and let FRC take care of interactions with the UI. FRC delegate gets new data by:

```
- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
{
  //self.places = [self sortPlaces:controller.fetchedObjects];

  self.places = controller.fetchedObjects;

  [self.delegate contentUpdatedInDatasource:self];
}
```

I disabled the sorting by now, thought it could affect the main thread. I've tried figuring out what else could load the main thread with Time Profiler, but didn't find anything suspicious. [screenshot](http://i57.tinypic.com/kaiqrn.png)

When all the data is loaded everything run smoothly, the app lags only at the first start, when the DB gets populated. Since everything loading-related is held by RestKit i don't think it causes problems.

I was thinking of delaying requests by 10 per second max, but have no idea how can i achieve it. Basically, on the start app gets and array of IDs(~250 by now) and then looping trough the array and requesting data from the server by each ID. It's not so crucial so far, but when the array grow up to 1-2k it would be a big problem. Btw, a single data object has 4 relationships in the DB. Is reducing dependencies a possible solution?

UPDATE:
I've tried to split the request to 1 by 1 and it caused a pretty weird behaviour.
For some reason there's a huge delay between requests.
This is how i get an array of IDs

```
        AFJSONRequestOperation *op = [[AFJSONRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[APIRoot stringByAppendingFormat:@"/venues/listId?%@=%@&%@=%@", TokenKey, [DEUser token], UDIDKey, [DEUser udid]]]]];

        // dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0);
        dispatch_queue_t backgroundQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.name.bgqueue", NULL);
        op.successCallbackQueue = backgroundQueue;

        [op setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
             //gettin an array of IDs
            NSArray *array = (NSArray*) responseObject;
            if(array.count)
            {
                _array = array;
                [self getVenuesFromSelfArrayWithCurrentIndex:0];
            }
        } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
            NSLog(@"3rr0r: %@", error);
        }];

        [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperation:op];
```

And this is a code of recursive method:

```
- (void)getVenuesFromSelfArrayWithCurrentIndex: (NSUInteger)index
{
if(index >= _array.count){ NSLog(@"loading finished!"); return; }
//version of the app, location e.t.c.
NSMutableDictionary *options = [[self options] mutableCopy];
[options setObject:[_array objectAtIndex:index] forKey:@"venueId"];
//method below calls RKs getObjectsAtPath, and it's pretty much the only thing it does
[[DEAPIService sharedInstance] getObjectsOfClass:[DEPlace class]
                                     withOptions:options
                                         success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult){
                                             NSManagedObject *object = [mappingResult.array firstObject];
                                             if([object isKindOfClass:[DEPlace class]])
                                             {
                                                 [self getVenuesFromSelfArrayWithCurrentIndex:index+1];
                                             }
                                         } failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error){
                                            NSLog(@"Failed to load the place with options: %@", options.description);
                                             [self getVenuesFromSelfArrayWithCurrentIndex:index+1];
                                         }];
}
```

The weird part is that it takes ~1-2 seconds(!) to start next request and cpu usage log and threads look.. strange.

[Screenshot 1](http://oi58.tinypic.com/2h3a35x.jpg)

[Screenshot 2](http://oi58.tinypic.com/voa4aw.jpg)

Any suggestions?

Comment: An FRC should always be attached to the main thread context - it's used by the UI so it can't use a background context (at least not trivially). So you are making 250 requests at the same time at launch?

Comment: Since i got it attached to rootSavingContext, therefore i guess it's attached to persistentStoreManagedObjectContext now. Correct, i got 250 startup requests. Sometimes app just locks(i thought it's gone, but i was wrong). And i single request is ~10-15Kb. Ofc i can divide requests into groups and so on, but i really need to understand what caused those lags.

Answer (score 0):

At this point in time I can only suggest around the 250 requests. You can't make more than around 4 or 5 concurrent network requests without flooding the network and grinding it to a halt on a mobile device. Really you should change the web service design so you can send batch requests as this is a lot more efficient both for the client and the server.

Anyway, you can limit the concurrent requests by setting the `maxConcurrentOperationCount` of the `operationQueue` of your object manager. The recommendation would be to set it to 4.

Comment: Hm. When i invoke RK's getObjectsAtPath does it create an RKRequestOperation? Would other 246 requests got put in a queue?

Comment: Yes, it creates operations for requests and others for mapping. 250 network requests isn't ideal ;-)

Comment: So should i consider reducing the amount of requests? I was thinking of doing some recursion to perform requests literally one by one.

Comment: Better to reduce request count by batching. Setting up and tearing down connections is costly so better to pack more into each request if it's a background type operation and not time sensitive

Comment: I've done some kind of "perverted batching" by myself and updated original post. Gonna check RK's Paginator.

Comment: Yeah, you're just pushing the tiniest bit of setup into a background thread and running your other code on main. It isn't batching either, it's rate limiting ;-). This isn't really a win, just overly complex. How are you measuring the 1-2 second delay?

Comment: I thought if i set the completion block queue for AFRequestOperation and put everything to a block it should run background. Won't my recursive stuff get called from and in a background if it's inside a block which operates at BG?
And of the delay: 1 mississippi, 2 mississippi, 3 mississippi... :D

Comment: Restkit will call the completion blocks on main. You only set the queue for the very first operation. I'd do all that on main as its light lifting and leave only the heavy lifting in background. For the 1-2 I mean between what, a request ending and the next starting? I'd recommend just changing the max concurrent as mentioned above...

Comment: Please check my latest update. There's gotta be no queues at all, just 1 by 1 calls to RK. I can't figure out what makes such a big delay. The loop goes request -> mapping -> %delay% -> request -> e.t.c.